# SwiftU NavigationView: how to update previous view every time coming back from the secondary view

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview

In ContentView.swift, I have:

```
List(recipeData) { recipe in NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipe: recipe)){
                        Text(recipe.name)
                     }
                 }
```

In the RecipeView, user might update the recipeData variable. However, when the RecipeView is closed, ContentView is not updated based on the updated recipeData.

recipeData is not a @State array but a normal one that is declared outside the ContentView struct. I cannot easily make it a @State var because it is used in other parts of the app.

Thanks!

Comment: I would make `recipeData` wrapped with `@ObservedObject` (so conforming it to `ObservableObject`)

Answer (score 0):

Using `@ObservableObject` and `@Published` you can achieve your requirements.

**ViewModel**

```
final class RecipeListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recipeData: [Recipe] = []
    ....
    ....

    //write code to fetch recipes from the server or local storage and fill the recipeData

    ....
    ....

}
```

**View**

```
struct RepositoryListView : View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: RecipeListViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.recipeData) { recipe in 
            NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipe: recipe)) {
                Text(recipe.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```